# storing and accessing static NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have the following:

```
@implementation DataSource
+ (NSArray *)someData
{
  static NSArray *data = nil;
  if (!data) {
    data = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:..., nil] retain];
  }
  return data;
}
@end
```

Is there a way to access the class method from the class it self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *array = [DataSource someData];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *accessor = [DataSource someData];
```

The + refers to [class level access](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#class).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Inside a class method like your someData you can call another class method like

```
[self anotherClassMethod].
```

Here self refers to class.

Answer (score 0):

a static method can be called with name of class. Above static method return type NSArray so we can use anywhere

```
NSArray  *Arr=[DataSource someData];
```

Answer (score 0):

In other class methods, you can call it as `[self someData]`. From instances of the class, you can call it as `[[self class] someData]` (this has the nice property that subclasses can override it and their implementations will automatically be used as appropriate). From outside the class, you can call it as `[DataSource someData]`.

BTW, if this is actually meant to be the data source for some Cocoa or Cocoa Touch class such as NS/UITableView, you should probably implement the class as a singleton instead of making the class itself the data source, because using classes as data sources is not well-tested and the lack of instance variables will probably become a pain as your program grows.